# How do I update a Column in SQL from one table using a different table with SQL Alchemy?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I have 2 tables, `table1` is a running inventory list and `table2` is the updated sales for the day. How would I update the tables `Sold` field to reflect the update in inventory on table1? I tried using:

````
FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.SKU = table2.SKU ```

I'm using the Python module: SQL Alchemy to do this, and am getting "(sqlite3.OperationalError) near ".": syntax error".

Any ideas?
````

Comment: If my solution has answered your question, kindly mark it as accepted to close this off. If the issue remains, please post an update and I’ll do my best to assist

Answer (score 0):

This is an sqlite error; nothing to do with Python or SQLAlchemy

You've got your sqlite syntax all mixed up; you need to use a subquery rather than a join

See section 2.2 from the docs [here](https://sqlite.org/lang_update.html)

```
UPDATE table1
SET Sold = table1.Sold +
(
    SELECT Sold
    FROM table2
    WHERE table1.SKU = table2.SKU
)
```